# Can't print correctly to Brother HL-2140 laser printer from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and connected to Cups which found my Brother HL-2140 printer. I then printed a test page and the printer began putting out an endless amount of blank pages. Turned the printer off and tried to print from Firefox. Did the same thing - printed an endless amount of blank pages. This printer was previously working with Xubuntu 12.04.

Is there a driver I need to download or something else I have to do to get it to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a HL-2240 and had a similar problem. Brother has an [Install Tool here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=au&lang=en&prod=hl2140_all&os=128), you might have better luck selecting **HL2170W** instead of HL2140 though. The install directions pop up after you accept the EULA to download.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yeah, the HL-2240 definitely didn't go so well. Got errors on the install and then made the mistake of trying to print a test page as it offered, and it did the infinite loop printing blank pages. I shut the printer off to stop it, but that was a mistake. I now have a page jammed that will not come out without some kind of disassembly. It is one thing to write a driver that doesn't work - or have print system that doesn't work. But how did they manage a print system with an infinite loop?

Comment: Was able to print the test page successfully using the HL-2170W printer driver! But unfortunately, infinite looped blank pages when I printed 1 page from Firefox. :( That infinite loop, or one page per character, or whatever it is doing is a killer. Really bad stuff.

Comment: OK, it does work! I just had to select HL-2170W as the printer and not HL-2240.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from a long time ago. But I got the **Brother HL-2140** to work on Ubuntu by doing the following:

**(1)** ***Add the Printer Normally (If not already added) :*** Plug the printer into your computer with the USB. Go to printers and add the printer normally.

**(2) *Change driver :*** Double click on the Brother printer to open properties. [( Image of printer properties )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEml1.png) Click the *"Change"* button beside *"Make and Model"*. Select *"Brother"* (if not already selected) and then click "*Forward*". [(Change Driver Window)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlLq2.png) Select a driver other than the *"Foomatic/Postcript"* (or the current driver). I selected the "*Footmatic/hl1250 [en]*" Driver.

**(3)** ***Existing Settings:*** On this page I selected *"Try to copy the option settings over from old PPD"* and clicked apply. Print a test page. If you still get continues blank pages, change the driver and try again. This method worked for me on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (32-bit)**.